# Non-linear curve (multi-peak) fitting

Tags: python, excel, curve-fitting, smoothing, cdf

Need help smoothening the red graph below to something that looks like blue graph.

[image]

I have tried moving average, problem with that is, it didn't remove the noise, further shifts the position of the curve. I would like to maintain the same position and area under the curve (here it is 100%). Is fitting multiple small curves the solution here? or is a way to fit a curve to this in python or excel?

Comment: Use a moving average of adjacent points. Instead of taking the most recent 6 points (for example) take 3 points to the left and 3 points to the right. This prevents a horizontal shift of the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options available. For instance, you could either use a [Gaussian](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d.html) or a [Savitzky-Golay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) filter.

Considering a noisy signal (1D numpy array), like this one:
[image]

the following snippet allows you to denoise it. Change the parameters according to your particular use case:

```py
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

np.random.seed(42)

x = np.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 300)
y = f(x) # your signal

y_gaussian = gaussian_filter1d(y, 3)
y_savgol = savgol_filter(y, 8, 2)

plt.plot(x, y, label="Noisy Signal")
plt.plot(x, y_gaussian, label="Gaussian Filter")
plt.plot(x, y_savgol, label="Savgol Filter")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

and zooming-in to see more details:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @blunova.This works perfectly! Ran this and then solved for 100% auc in excel.